# Is it possible to automatically re-indexing of the Plone catalog regulary?

Tags: python, plone

I want to re-index the Plone catalog automaticaly and on regular basis.
What are the advantage and disadvatage of doing so?

Comment: Please ask Plone questions in our forum, https://community.plone.org where more people will see them and be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that, for example by creating a small python script and run through instance (`bin/instance1 run <your py script file>`) and run it through cronjob.

My intention here to share with you, my real-life experience if your system's Database is large it could take reindexing more than days! so that would be unrealistic to plan frequent re-indexing, beside frequent re-reindexing, would not give you performance optimization (could benefit for broken indexes), instead, you could do pack your database frequently, that will give you performance 
https://docs.plone.org/manage/deploying/packing.html

Comment: There is usually no need to force a reindexing of the catalog on a regular basis. Normally, the catalog indexes should be maintaining themselves correctly on item creation and edits. What is the problem you are trying to solve? And again, it's best to ask in the forum instead.

Comment: @T.KimNguyen my problem is that our zodb database size is larger than 80GB (complex dexterity contents), Maybe my mistake, I thought it's normal to take more than a day to do full reindexing, but if you think this is abnormal, I will post in our plone forum.